# This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'string' have no overlap ngIf

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I have a DIV with few ngIf conditions. But I recently added a new condition after that it triggers an error saying **This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'number' and 'string' have no overlap**

```
<div class="row" *ngIf="epmo===true && isHistory===true && myChangeRequest.requestStatus==='0'">
```

I tried initially myChangeRequest.requestStatus===0 which was not working which I dont know since requestStatus is number type. Then I tried with single quotes way which then working but this error

Comment: What types are the variables `epmo`, `myChangeRequest.requestStatus`? Try changing `myChangeRequest.requestStatus === ` to only 2 `==` if you would like to use 'truthy' values and no type checking.

Comment: what is your myChangeRequest.requestStatus type ? Can u share your myChangeRequest model in code

Comment: What are the different data types for your variables?

Comment: Sorry bit late.. I guess I mentioned in the question requestStatus is number type

Answer (score 2):

From the error-message that you provided, we can assume that `myChangeRequest.requestStatus` is of type number.

so the following comparison should work:

```
*ngIf="epmo===true && isHistory===true && myChangeRequest.requestStatus===0"
```

see this [Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9bckfp)

- you can change `AppComponent.requestStatus` to e.g. `1`, then the `div content` will be gone

If this does not work, then you must provide more info:

- what is the data-type of `myChangeRequest.requestStatus`?
- what error do you get in this case?

Comment: My requestStatus is number type. but it was not working when === 0 . It worked only when ==='0'. But this error

Comment: @SandeepThomas and what exactly was not working - i.e. what did you expect and what was happening instead?

Comment: I was expecting to hide the div when the value 0. But its not when I am not specify without single quotes. It working with single quotes but shows that error

Comment: Then you must debug it to find out what's the real cause. e.g. you could compute the condition in your component or add some debug-info to the template. I've improved my Stackblitz example: see `AppComponent.debugCondition` and the additional output in the template

Comment: I'm really sorry to say its coming from server as string "0"

Comment: well, that happens quite often - the important thing is that you now found out the real cause and can fix it: e.g. the server should really send a number - or in your client side http code you should cast it to a string/or convert it to a number (when you cannot change the server-code)

Comment: You are awesome buddy.. Thanks a lot